# Displaying dynamic value in struts

Tags: struts, jstl

I m trying to display a value from database to struts.

If I use `<html:text>` the value is displayed in the text box.

```
<html:text  property="tCG.year"  size="6"></html:text>
```

But, if same property when I try to display as label using `${tCG.year}` the value is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<html:text property="tCG.year/>` means "display a text box filled with the property `year` of the property `tCG` of the form bean associated to the enclosing `html:form`".

So, if the form bean associated to the form is named `myCoolForm`, the expression you should use is `${myCoolForm.tCG.year}`